# Powershell replace function - replacing lines with numbers

Tags: powershell, replace

Basicly I am trying to find a way to put a variable for replacing a line in powershell.

The current script:

```
$switches = get-outlookinbox | where subject -eq "Hello"
    $e = $switches.body
    $e = $e.replace("Hello:","")
    $e = $e.replace(" Number","")
    $e = $e.replace(":1","")
    $e = $e.replace(":2","")
    $e = $e.replace(":3","")
    $e = $e.replace(":4","")
    $e = $e.replace(":99","")
```

You can see what I am going for here... But I don't want 99 lines of replace code, any thoughts on this?
Also, the numbers MUST have : infront of it, otherwise the replace will corrupt the file since it contains only IP's and ports, it's the ports I want to remove from the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple [`foreach` loop](http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/logic-using-loops/) and iterate from `99` to `1`:

```powershell
foreach ($n in 99..1)
{
    $e = $e.Replace(":$n", " ")
}
```

Or, if you prefer one line:

```powershell
foreach ($n in 99..1) { $e = $e.Replace(":$n", " ") }
```

Demo:

```powershell
PS > $mystr = "a:1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10:11:12:13:14:15:16:17:18:19:20b"  
PS > foreach ($n in 20..1) { $mystr = $mystr.replace(":$n", "") }
PS > $mystr
ab 
PS >
```

Comment: Conveniently your demo only goes up to 9... if it went into double digits it would be very obvious that this does not work

Comment: @Cole9350 - Ah, my mistake.  I should be iterating in reverse.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions : regex101.com

`$e = $e -replace ':\d+',""`

No loops necessary

Answer (score 2):

Might as well get 'em all while you're at it:

```
$e -replace 'Hello:| Number|:\d{1,2}'
```